# Run tests with coverage in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android-studio, junit, robolectric, test-coverage

In the new version of Android Studio, *2.3 Canary*, I no longer have the "Run with Coverage..." option for tests.

Does anyone know if the option was somehow **integrated into another mechanism**, or was it **removed altogether**?

I hope not, that would be really bad, as I strongly relied on it when doing TDD with Robolectric :-( While the option to put a picture in the editor background is nice - having a cat stare at me for 8h is cool - not getting coverage reports is a rather high price to pay... :-(

Comment: I'm not sure on the underlying reason (deliberate or bug), but there is an open issue for this here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227604&q=coverage%202.3&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is back in Android Studio 2.3 Canary 3! :D

---

**EDIT:**

However, it seems broken :-( After running it once the IDE decided to say I have no tests in the suite :-(

However, there is a way to enable it in 2.3.2:

1. Download 2.3.3., open the archive, go to folder named **plugin**, then to **coverage** and copy the *BUILD* file you will find in there.
2. Go to your 2.3.2. installation, and also open **plugin** and then **coverage** (the plugin was in 2.3. all the time, just inactive!)
3. Paste the *BUILD* file here and start Android Studio 2.3.2. You should now have access to Run with Coverage option :-D